# I can not generate auto-incremented Id and hibernate always generate 1 as Id

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I am a bit disconcerted with this and I am asking for help just in order to understand what is happening.

**So, I have this table (DDL):**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  KEY `FK17herqt2to4hyl5q5r5ogbxk9` (`image_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK17herqt2to4hyl5q5r5ogbxk9` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES    `images` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_users_images1` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `images` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**And my entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6304869652591140818L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @Transient
    private String password;

   @Column(name = "enabled")
   private int enabled;

   @Column(name = "created_at")
   private LocalDateTime createdAt;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "users_has_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
   private Set<Role> roles;

   @MapsId
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Image image;

   // Setters and Getters
}
```

**I am trying to persist a new User with this code:**

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public void createUser(NewUserDto newUser) {

    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstname(newUser.getFirstname());
    user.setLastname(newUser.getLastname());
    user.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
    user.setEnabled(ENABLED);
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(newUser.getPassword()));

    Image userImage = imageService.getImageById(1L);
    user.setProfileImage(userImage);


    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    Role role = roleRepository.findByName(newUser.getRole());
    roles.add(role);

    user.setRoles(roles);

    if (user.getId() == null) {
        em.persist(user);
        em.flush();
    } else {
        em.merge(user);
    }

}
```

The thing is that when I debug I see that always generates id=1 for the new user.

But in the database, I see all correct.

[image]

**And when i search for all users i get the following:**

```
public List<User> getAll() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

[image]

The same JPDA ObjectReference.

Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*(Apologies for not having enough reputation to leave a comment)*

I do not understand your question clearly. Anyway i will try to explain based on what I think is your problem.

- By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will
  increment by 1 for each new record. So that behavior is expected.
- If you want it to start with a value that is not 1, then you must use
  a GenerationType.SEQUENCE with appropriate changes.
- Image1: You have mentioned that the values are getting entered into
  the database correctly and this shows that the Id values are being
  generated correctly
- Image2: users is a Javascript array. Index values of javascript
  arrays always start from zero. That is just the index value and NOT
  the id value. Similarly, the id mentioned on the right is the
  javascript's internal object id and not the actual Id of your user.
- To see the real id of the user, expand the user at position 0.

If this does not answer your questions, kindly elaborate your question and what exactly is the error or issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from a misunderstanding where Hibernate's fallback for `GenerationType.AUTO` is `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, while what most people want is `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, so you can use the id the database assigns you. simply change the strategy to `IDENTITY` and your problem is solved.